# I need to create a query with a dynamic range of value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column called "Points", the value of this column have a min value of 0, and a max value of 100.000. I have to do an analysis per range of this column, so I wrote a query like this:

```
select  case when Points between 0 and 5000 then '0 - 5000'
             when Points between 5001 and 20000 then '50001 - 20000'
             when Points > 20000 then '> 20000'
        else 0 end RangeP
from Sales
```

The problem is that the customer wants to see for each 2.000 points from 0 to 100.000

If I wrote the query using the case, the query will get really big, so I'd like one way to get dynamically this range.

It is possible? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a table which contains the ranges, and their text labels, and then join to it, e.g.

```
SELECT
    s.Points,
    COALESCE(r.label, 'range not found') AS range
FROM Sales s
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 0 AS start, 2000 AS end, '0 - 2000' AS label UNION ALL
    SELECT 2001, 4000, '2001 - 4000' UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT 98000, 100000, '98000 - 100000'
) r
    ON s.Points BETWEEN r.start AND r.end;
```

I have inlined the table of ranges, but you may create a formal table (or maybe a temp table) instead, and then replace the above subquery with just a reference to that table.

Comment: Thank you Tim, i will try this way.